# Reference outer component in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

As an example I have a basic component with two public properties (for brevity I have ommited the outer `FormGroup` from the example.

```
public sentiment: FormArray;
public sentimentValues: ['terrible', 'neutral', 'good'];
```

In the view I am iterating over the controls that are contained in the `sentiment` array.

```
<div *ngFor="let option of sentiment.controls; index as i;">
    <label [for]="'sentiment_' + i" class="sentimentLabel">
      <input class="sentiment"
             [id]="'sentiment_' + i"
             type="checkbox"
             name="sentiment"
             [formControl]="option"
             value="option1">
    </label>
</div>
```

I would like to add a class to the `label` element that is at the index of `i` in the `sentimentValues` array within an ngFor loop.

```
<label [ngClass]="sentimentValues[i]">...</label>
```

This yields an error `_co.sentimentValues is undefined`

How can I access the outer components value within the ngFor loop? (or how can I re-factor this so that maybe the `sentimentValues` array is just not required?

(Additional but related, the `[value]` of the input should also be the value of `sentimentValues[i]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Your array initialization is incorrect, you need to be using `=`:

```
public sentimentValues = ['terrible', 'neutral', 'good'];
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo when writing the question. The names are correct and I've updated the question, thanks for the spot.

Comment: What a stupid mistake, it was driving me crazy. Thanks! (will accept when it lets me)

Comment: One of those unfortunate times when typescripts expressive type definitions actual work against you and consider that a valid type set :p

Comment: Yes indeed, makes me wonder how much faith I put in IDE's as well. :-) Thanks again.